# Problems installing phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, centos7

I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin on a Centos 7 / PHP 5.6 installation. Unfortunately, upgrading to PHP 7.* is not really possible yet, due to delays in application migration.

When I try yum install phpmyadmin I get:

```
Error: php56u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64
Error: php71u-common conflicts with php56u-common-5.6.33-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: php71u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Using --skip-broken etc. doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: read the error messages, you need to remove old php first. also show how your attempting to install.

Comment: Try `yum erase php-common` first

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by removing, then reinstalling php:

```
yum remove php php-mysql php-fpm
yum install php php-mysql php-fpm
yum install phpmyadmin
```